# Swift iOS -How to compress stored embedded video file size?

Tags: ios, swift, video, compression, testflight

I saved a video in FCP as `h.264`. I dragged the video into the Project Navigator section of Xcode and Selected Copy Items if Needed. It's a `.mov` that plays in the background of the Login page when it's presented.

[image]

This is how I access and play the video:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleVideo", withExtension: ".mov")

    player = AVPlayer.init(url: url!)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer?.frame = view.layer.frame
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
    player?.play()
    view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
```

The problem is when the video is included inside my project and I upload the app to TestFlight the file size is `304 MB`. I get a warning about the app's max size exceeding the 150 MB limit.

[image]

I know the user can still download it but I notice if the connection is slow it takes quite a while for the app to download.

If I delete the video from my project and upload the app to TestFlight the compressed file size is greatly reduced to `38.2 MB`

[image]

**How can I keep the video inside my app and reduce the file size of my app?**

I would assume compressing the video inside Xcode would achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recorded my app's background video on an iPhone 7+ using FilmicPro. Everything was recorded in 4K. As the question states the file size was very high after it was uploaded to iTunesConnect. What I did to get around the issue was convert my 4K video to 1080P. I used FCPX and the conversion took a few minutes. The quality looked exactly the same.

Here's the YouTube video I followed on how to create the conversion. It's very easy to follow and is less then 5 minutes:

[YouTube -Convert video from 4K to 1080P](https://youtu.be/M1bVC3c57ok)